# How deos the Node.js HTTP module determine the end of a single HTTP request?

Tags: node.js

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write("hello");
  res.end();
})
```

With nodejs http module, we can write a simple server that response "hello" like above.

But I learned that http request message may not arrive at once.
So I think http module should accumulate request entered to server, validate accumulated request is valid HTTP request, and once the http request is validated, it then runs logic.

I want to know how HTTP module handles it. Does it check "content-length" header and body length are the same? What if there is no "content-length" header because "content-length" header is not mandatory?